# Reverse Byte-Order of a postgres bytea field

Tags: postgresql, psql, bytea

I'm currently working on a table that contains hashes, stored in bytea format. Converting the hashes to hex-strings however yields the wrong order of bytes. Example:

```
SELECT encode(hash, 'hex') FROM mytable LIMIT 1;

Output: 1a6ee4de86143e81
Expected: 813e1486dee46e1a
```

Is there a way to reverse the order of bytes for all entries?

Comment: Why do you expect the hash to be reversed byte-wise? That's ... weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one method of doing it, however **I would never do this.** There is nothing wrong with storing bytes in a database's `bytea` column. But, I wouldn't bit wrangle in the database, and if I did I would use,

- a [C language function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/xfunc-c.html), or
- some fancy procedural language that didn't require me exploding the inputs into a set of bytes.

This is sql-esque and should work -- here is what we're doing,

1. Generate a set consisting of a series of offsets *0 - (bytelength-1)*.
2. Map those offsets to bytes represented as strings of hex.
3. String aggregate them in reverse order.

Here is an example,

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT '\x813e1486dee46e1a'::bytea AS bar;

SELECT bar, string_agg(to_hex(byte), '') AS hash
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT get_byte(bar,"offset") AS byte
  FROM generate_series(0,octet_length(bar)-1) AS x("offset")
  ORDER BY "offset" DESC
) AS x
GROUP BY bar;
```

Two notes,

1. We could probably not use `offset` because [it's reserved](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) but you get the point.
2. This assumes that your hash (bar in the above) is UNIQUE.

Answer (score 4):

If you need just to reverse bytes in the `bytea` value there is the (relatively) simple and fast solution using [`plpythonu`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html):

```
create or replace function reverse_bytea(p_inp bytea) returns bytea stable language plpythonu as $$
  b = bytearray()
  b.extend(p_inp)
  b.reverse()
  return b
$$;

select encode(reverse_bytea('\x1a6ee4de86143e81'), 'hex');
----
813e1486dee46e1a
```

However I suppose that something wrong with data itself (the storage way, the data interpretation...)

Comment: I think you should have went the extra distance if you're going to use plpython: you should have returned the hex-encoded string.

Comment: @EvanCarroll And convert the result back to `bytea` if somebody needs just reverse the value? IMO one function - one task. However it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 4):

Solutions with tools in vanilla Postgres:

I added a column `bytea_reverse` to both solutions. Remove it if you don't need it.

With [`get_byte()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-OTHER):

```
SELECT t.b, text_reverse, decode(text_reverse, 'hex') AS bytea_reverse
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(to_hex(get_byte(b, x)), '') AS text_reverse
   FROM   generate_series(octet_length(t.b) - 1, 0, -1) x
   ) x ON true;
```

This is similar to what [@Evan provided](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156706/3684). Most of his excellent explanation applies. But:

- Use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true` or you lose rows with NULL values.
- `generate_series()` can provide numbers in reverse, so we do not need another `ORDER BY` step.
- While using a `LATERAL` join, aggregate in the subquery. Less error prone, easier to integrate with more complex queries, and no need to `GROUP BY` in the outer query.

With `regexp_matches()`:

```
SELECT t.b, text_reverse, decode(text_reverse, 'hex') AS bytea_reverse
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(byte[1], '' ORDER  BY ord DESC) AS text_reverse
   FROM   regexp_matches(encode(t.b, 'hex' ), '..', 'g' ) WITH ORDINALITY AS x(byte, ord)
   ) x ON true;
```

This is similar to the ["verbose" variant @filiprem provided](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156706/3684). But:

- Use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true` or you lose rows with NULL values.
- Use `WITH ORDINALITY` to get row numbers "for free". So we neither need another subquery with `row_number()` nor a double `reverse()`. Details:

  - [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- Reverse ordering can be done in the aggregate function. (But it might be a bit faster to order in the subquery and add another subquery layer to aggregate pre-ordered rows.)
- One subquery (or two) instead of two CTE is typically faster.

---

Similar question on SO:

- [Convert bigint to bytea, but swap the byte order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142235/convert-bigint-to-bytea-but-swap-the-byte-order)

Comment: The main disadvantage is that the SQL/PLSQL is much slower then the other scripting languages like Python/Perl/TCL/Java for the scalar code which does not acts with data in the DB. At this point of view the using of the "C language function" as suggested by @Evan is the best solution but it is somewhere complicated for the distribution.

Comment: @Abelisto: Yup, a C function should be faster by orders of magnitude - especially for `bytea` values longer than a couple of bytes.

Answer (score 3):

You could treat encoded representation as text and use regexp to reverse byte by byte.

```
SELECT string_agg(reverse(b[1]),'')
FROM regexp_matches(reverse(encode('STUFF','hex')),'..','g')b;
```

Another (more verbose) method:

```
WITH bytes AS (
  SELECT row_number() over() AS n, byte[1]
  FROM regexp_matches( encode( 'STUFF', 'hex' ), '..', 'g' ) AS byte
), revbytes AS (
  SELECT * FROM bytes ORDER BY n DESC
)
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(byte),'')
FROM revbytes;
```

Sample usage:

```
(filip@[local:/var/run/postgresql]:5432) filip=# SELECT encode( 'STUFF', 'hex' );
   encode   
------------
 5354554646
(1 row)

(filip@[local:/var/run/postgresql]:5432) filip=# SELECT string_agg(reverse(b[1]),'')FROM regexp_matches(reverse(encode('STUFF','hex')),'..','g')b;
 string_agg 
------------
 4646555453
(1 row)
```

Comment: Nice catch. I thought about `regexp_matches` and `reverse` but not guessed about double-`reverse` :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all the suggestions, I wrote this C-Language-Function that works as needed:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
    PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

Datum bytea_custom_reverse(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(bytea_custom_reverse);
Datum
bytea_custom_reverse(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
  bytea *data = PG_GETARG_BYTEA_P_COPY(0);
  unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *) VARDATA(data);

  int32 dataLen = VARSIZE(data) - VARHDRSZ;

  unsigned char *start, *end;

  for ( start = ptr, end = ptr + dataLen - 1; start < end; ++start, --end ) {
    unsigned char swap = *start;
    *start = *end;
    *end = swap;
  }


  PG_RETURN_BYTEA_P(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping this thread. And this is my choose of convert bigint to bytea in littleEndian like in C# using BitConverter.GetBytes() according on answers:

```
with mycte as (
select int8send(394112768534335::bigint) as conversionValue
)
SELECT decode(string_agg (
  (case when get_byte(conversionValue, x)<= 15 then ('0')  else  '' end) ||
  to_hex(get_byte(conversionValue, x))
  , ''), 'hex') AS nativeId_reverse  
   FROM mycte,  generate_series(octet_length(conversionValue) - 1, 0, -1) as x;
```

For search value placed in postgresql as littleEndian byteA by it Bigint presentation:

```
with mycte as (
select int8send(394112768534335::bigint) as conversionValue
)
Select * FROM mycte, *SomeByteaFieldTable*
where *SomeByteaId* =                                                                         
(SELECT decode(string_agg (
  (case when get_byte(conversionValue, x)<= 15 then ('0')  else  '' end) ||
  to_hex(get_byte(conversionValue, x))
  , ''), 'hex') AS nativeId_reverse  
   FROM   generate_series(octet_length(conversionValue) - 1, 1, -1) x);
```

Comment: This looks like a programming question and not a programming one!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer of R. Martin, I created the pg_bswap extension that can reverse byte order for various data types, with decent speed:

https://github.com/pandrewhk/pg_bswap

Comment: Unless you give more details, this may be considered as just spam.

Answer (score 0):

Was curious if there's a simple way to reverse bytea strings without dealing with hex or regex.

In case someone finds it useful, here's what I came up with:

```sql
create or replace function bytea_reverse(bytea)
returns bytea
language sql immutable parallel safe
return (
    select string_agg(substring($1 from byte_pos for 1), '')
      from generate_series(octet_length($1), 1, -1) as byte_pos);
```

I also had the need to output integers in little endian format that the above function can easily do with `bytea_reverse(int4send(x))`, but since we know it is always 4 bytes, this is about 30% faster:

```sql
create or replace function public.int4send_le(int)
returns bytea
language sql immutable parallel safe
return
(select int4send( $1 << 24
               | ($1 <<  8 & 16711680)
               | ($1 >>  8 & 65280)
               | ($1 >> 24 & 255)));
```

These correctly reverse both positive and negative integers as bytea:

```
select int4send(i), int4send_le(i), bytea_reverse(int4send(i)) from generate_series(-2,1) i;

  int4send  | int4send_le | bytea_reverse 
------------+-------------+---------------
 \xfffffffe | \xfeffffff  | \xfeffffff
 \xffffffff | \xffffffff  | \xffffffff
 \x00000000 | \x00000000  | \x00000000
 \x00000001 | \x01000000  | \x01000000
```