# Postgres - Return default value if regex match fails

Tags: postgresql, functions, pattern-matching, regex, set-returning-functions

I'd like to attempt a regex match, and return `null` if it fails.

The following query attempts to find the first number in a string. The result ignores the entry with text `'blah'`. I'd prefer it to return a `null` value instead.

This question is probably less about regex and more about set algebra. My hunch is that there is an elegant way to do it, without needing to `left join` anything, though googling is proving futile.

```
with test_data as (
  select 'abc 123' as txt
  union
  select 'abc 456' as txt
  union
  select 'blah' as txt
)

select
  txt,
  (regexp_matches(txt, '\d+'))[1] as first_num
from
  test_data
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While [your answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210049/3684) *solves* the problem with `regexp_matches()`, the much better solution is to *avoid* the problem with the more appropriate function [**`substring()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) to begin with:

```
WITH test_data(txt) AS (
   VALUES
      (text 'abc 123')
    , ('abc 456')
    , ('blah')
   )
SELECT txt, substring(txt FROM '\d+') AS first_num
FROM   test_data;
```

Does exactly what you need: returns the first match in the string or `NULL` for *no match*.

`substring(string FROM pattern)` is standard SQL syntax.
Don't confuse it with `substring(string [FROM int] [FOR int])` or `substring(string FROM pattern FOR escape)` doing something else.

You can also use the shorter, equivalent, currently undocumented Postgres implementation `substring(text, text)` (with comma (`,`) instead of `FROM`).

Use [`regexp_matches()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to return *all* matches as *set*. (Note that a single regexp can result in multiple matches, hence a set of text *arrays*). You still only get the first row unless you add the flag `'g'` to get all rows (additional matches - if any - for the same regexp). Related:

- [Reverse Byte-Order of a postgres bytea field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156700/reverse-byte-order-of-a-postgres-bytea-field/157059#157059)

To avoid complications move set-returning functions to the `FROM` list in versions before Postgres 10:

- [What is the expected behavior for multiple set-returning functions in select clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864815/939860)

Or use [`regexp_match()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) in Postgres 10 or later to only return the first row. This would also not exhibit the original problem:

```
WITH test_data(txt) AS (
   VALUES
      (text 'abc 123')
    , ('abc 456')
    , ('blah')
   )
SELECT txt, (regexp_match(txt, '\d+'))[1] AS first_num
from   test_data;
```

But just use `substring()` for your purpose.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9a78afe848642cb9be496442b82b84ee)*

Answer (score 1):

**Use a sub-select.**

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html):

> It is possible to force regexp_matches() to always return one row by using a sub-select; this is particularly useful in a SELECT target list when you want all rows returned, even non-matching ones

The solution is:

```
with test_data as (
  select 'abc 123' as txt
  union
  select 'abc 456' as txt
  union
  select 'blah' as txt
)

select
  txt,
  (select regexp_matches(txt, '\d+'))[1] as first_num
from
  test_data
```

Answer (score 0):

minor optimization. also match optional prefix numeric value characters  **`+-.`**

```
WITH test_data (
    txt
) AS (
    VALUES (text 'abc 123'),
        ('abc 456'),
        ('blah'),
        ('11blah'),
        ('-.1-blah'),
        ('.1-blah'),
        ('-1-blah'),
        ('+.123'),
        ('abc+456'),
        ('abc-456'),
        ('abc-.456'),
        ('1.1-'),
        ('+11'))
SELECT
    txt,
    substring(txt FROM '[-+]?[.]?\d+')::numeric AS regex_num
FROM
    test_data;
```